# ¿Como corregir una variable indefinida en una vista en laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, undefined

tengo este código en un controlador de mi aplicación en laravel, es una consulta con joins y paginate para enviar la variable $salida (y otras dos mas) a una vista.

```
$tipo_salida = TipoSalida::all();
$cliente = Cliente::all();

$salida = DB::table("tbl_salidas")
->join("tbl_tipo_salida", "tbl_salidas.IdTipoSalida", "=", "tbl_tipo_salida.IdTipoSalida")
->join("tbl_clientes", "tbl_salidas.IdCliente", "=", "tbl_clientes.IdCliente")
->join("tbl_estados", "tbl_salidas.IdEstado", "=", "tbl_estados.IdEstado")
->select("tbl_salidas.IdSalida", "tbl_tipo_salida.Nombre as TipoDeSalida", 
"tbl_clientes.Nombre as Cliente", "tbl_salidas.DireccionCliente", "tbl_salidas.TelefonoCliente", "tbl_salidas.Fecha", "tbl_salidas.Total", "tbl_estados.Nombre")
->paginate(8);



return view ('administrador/salidas', compact('salida','tipo_salida','cliente'));
```

Este es el código que estoy poniendo en la vista para imprimir esa variable $salida que esta llegando

```
@if($salida->isEmpty())
                              <div align="center"><b>No hay Registros</b></div>
                            @else
                            <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                              <thead>
                                <tr>
                                  <th>Salida</th>
                                  <th>Tipo de Salida</th>
                                  <th>Cliente</th>
                                  <th>Fecha</th>
                                  <th>Dirección</th>
                                  <th>Teléfono</th>
                                  <th>Total</th>
                                  <th>Estado</th>                                
                                </tr>
                              </thead>
                              <tbody>
                                @foreach($salida as $sl)
                                  <tr>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td></td>
                                    <td>
                                      <form action="">
                                          <div class="form-group">
                                            <select  class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
                                              <option>Cancelada</option>
                                              <option>En deuda</option>
                                              <option>Anulada</option>
                                            </select>
                                          </div>
                                      </form>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                       <button type="button" class="btn btn-success"><i class='fa fa-print'></i></button>
                                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><i class='fa fa-eye'></i></button> 
                                    </td>
                                  </tr>
                                @endforeach  
                              </tbody>
                              <tfoot>
                                <tr>
                                  <th>Salidas</th>
                                  <th>Tipo de salida</th>
                                  <th>Cliente</th>
                                  <th>Fecha</th>
                                  <th>Dirección</th>
                                  <th>Teléfono</th>
                                  <th>Total</th>
                                  <th>Estado</th>
                                </tr>
                              </tfoot>
                            </table>
                            @endif
                            <div align="center">
                              {{ $salida->render() }}
                            </div>
```

El problema es que cuando voy a ver esto me arroja el siguiente error

> Undefined variable: salida (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\FruverSystemLaravel\resources\views\administrador\salidas.blade.php)

Quisiera saber si omití algo o que pueda ser lo que esta mal, muchas gracias.

Comment: Mete la variable salida en un arrayAsociativo y accede a ese arrayAsociativo en la vista

Comment: Ya intente usar el array asociativo y sigue apareciendo el error de la variable indefinida.

Comment: ¿qué muestra `dump($salida);` en el controlador? justo antes de hacer el return

Comment: @AndrésFelipe Mm hay algo que no nos estás mostrando, porque justo como lo estás poniendo no debería de haber ningún error...